# Which Graphic Card is faster?

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Here are 3 Graphic cards for review...

Configuration of **Bar** Graphic Card

```
Graphics Engine     AMD/ATI Radeon HD 5450
GPU Clock           650 MHz
Bus Standard        PCI Express 2.1
Memory              64-bit, 1 GB DDR3 Memory with 1000 MHz
```

Configuration **Foo** Graphic Card

```
Graphics Engine     AMD/ATI Radeon HD 5450
GPU Clock           650 MHz
Bus Standard        PCI Express 2.1
Memory              64-bit, 1 GB DDR3 Memory with 1100 MHz
```

Configuration of **FooBar** Graphic Card

```
Graphics Engine     AMD/ATI Radeon HD 5450
GPU Clock           650 MHz
Bus Standard        PCI Express 2.1
Memory              64-bit, 1 GB DDR3 Memory with 1334 MHz
```

It seems first 3 configuration is same for all Graphic Cards, Only a memory MHz difference, does higher MHz mean higher speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three cards are identical. Foo & FooBar simply have overclocked RAM modules, which offer almost nothing in terms of gaming performance. At best you may achieve an extra 1 frame per second via quicker texture fill and post processing with FooBar's higher clock, but this is only a benefit if all three cards cost the same.

In the end, this is simply a marketing gimmick that distributors use to differentiate their card (which is identical to all others) from their competitors. Buy the cheaper of the three.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. I am confused because price are same. Now I am cleared.